# Cakephp 2.x email not working, Why this Error comes

Tags: php, email, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I struck on this problem on many days. Please help. I have followed the cakephp documentation. but could not resolve issue.

```
Could not send email: unknown
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
```

Following is Configuration emai.php

```
<?php
class EmailConfig {

    public $default = array(
        'transport' => 'Mail',
        'from' => 'developer.support@sevenrocks.in',
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );

    public $smtp = array(
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'from' => array('site@localhost' => 'SevenRocks'),
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.sevenrocks.in',
        'port' => 465,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'developer.support@sevenrocks.in',
        'password' => 'developerofsevenrocks',
        'client' => null,
        'log' => true,
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );

}
```

Following is code in controller

```
$email = new CakeEmail();

$email->emailFormat('html');
$email->from(array($from_email => SITE_NAME));
$email->to($to);
$email->subject($subject);

if ($files)
{
    $email->attachments($files);
}

if ( !$email->send($content) )
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: to debug CakePHP 2x applications search for *debug* in your `app/Config/core.php` and change it to `Configure::write('debug', 2);` to see the full error message.

Second: Some providers may prevent you from sending Mails via PHP directly (*default* mail config). A better solution may to use the *smtp* configuration you provided in `email.php`.
To use your smtp configuration change your controller code to:

```
$email = new CakeEmail('smtp');

$email->emailFormat('html');
$email->to($to);
$email->subject($subject);
```

For more Info see https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#configuration